# TdxSpreadSheet xlsx file that contains other sheets, how to split them in separate xlsx?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have to save all different sheets in a xlsx file to csv by using FdxSpreadSheet.
I want to pass the current index of sheets to the load from file and save them by adding the index at the end of the name.
It doens't work and it always save the first sheet with different index name N times.
How can I load different Sheets and save them in different files ?

```
FdxSpreadSheet := TdxSpreadSheet.Create(nil);
try
  aFileText := ChangeFileExt(CurrentFile,'.csv');
  FdxSpreadSheet.LoadFromFile(CurrentFile);
  for I:=0 to  FdxSpreadSheet.SheetCount -1 do begin
    aFileText := ChangeFileExt(CurrentFile,IntToStr(I)+'.csv');
    FdxSpreadSheet.LoadFromFile(FdxSpreadSheet.Sheets[I]);
    FdxSpreadSheet.SaveToFile(aFileText);
    Result := aFileText;
    LogModule.ScriviLog('File convterd from XlsX to CSV ',Format(':[%s]',[aFileText]),tpLiv4);
  end;
finally
  FreeAndNil(FdxSpreadSheet);
end;
```

Comment: XLSX files can contain one or more sheets. CSV files have a single sheet. Your title and code don't really match and are confusing. Assuming you want to split a XLSX file into one CSV file per sheet I posted an answer of how to iterate over the sheets after multiple sheets are loaded form one XLSX file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadFromFile()` loads all the sheets if you load an xlsx file. Saving to CSV saves the currently active sheet so loop over the sheets.

```
  for a := 0 to dxSpreadSheet1.SheetCount -1 do
  begin
    dxSpreadSheet1.ActiveSheetIndex := a;
    dxSpreadSheet1.SaveToFile('Sheet_'+intToStr(a+1)+'.csv');
  end;
```

Note: Tested with Delphi 11 and DeveloperExpress VCL ExpressSpreadSheet 21.2.2

Comment: I've tested it on delphi 10.4 and VCL 21.1.6 but it doens't work ... It doesn't create the N files .csv

Comment: Fixed by adding a variable for SaveToFile. Now it works.

Comment: However is it possibile to retrive the name of the current sheet ?

Comment: @RedDot The caption property holds the name for a sheet. Ex. `dxSpreadSheet1.ActiveSheet.Caption`

Comment: Thanks I was missing that ActiveSheet reminds me to the current sheet.

Comment: How can I check the caption of columns of each sheets ? For the `FdxSpreadSheet.ActiveSheet` there isn't a .Column[INDEX].Caption ... 
I need to check if my first column is ID or others and if isn't ID add it.